# Why is caching values in objects taking more time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I have learnt, its better to cache the values in objects which we need repeatedly. For example, doing

```
var currentObj = myobject.myinnerobj.innermostobj[i]
```

and using 'currentObj' for further operations is better for performance than just

```
myobject.myinnerobj.innermostobj[i]
```

everywhere, like say in loops.. I am told it saves the script from looking-up inside the objects every time..

I have around 1000 lines of code, the only change I did to it with the intention of improving performance is this (at many locations) and the total time taken to execute it increased from 190ms to 230ms. Both times were checked using firebug 1.7 on Firefox 4.

Is what I learnt true (meaning either I am overusing it or mis-implemented it)? Or are there any other aspects to it that I am unaware of..?

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong but we cannot say without seeing the code ;)

Comment: :) I understand, but posting the code wont be possible for me.. :( So picked up the change that I did from the difference in the two versions and posted..

Comment: goto http://justpaste.it/ paste both versions of the code, so we can see please (I agree, 2000 lines of code would be hard to achieve here)

Comment: Mmmh. It should definitely be faster. Make sure that the variable is in local scope and .... well I don't know what there is more to say...

Comment: Is it possible that you're caching values that some code paths don't actually use?  Could you be caching things that are only used once?

Comment: Also @NikhilWanpal you should check out [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) as a way to try out small code tweaks.

Comment: And how is `currentObj` being used. Not being able to show the code is just shooting yourself in the foot. It s like a car mechanic not being able to open the hood to work on the engine.

Answer (score 1):

There is an initial cost for creating the variable, so you have to use the variable a few times (depending on the complexity of the lookup, and many other things) before you see any performance gain.

Also, how Javascript is executed has changed quite a bit in only a few years. Nowadays most browsers compile the code in some form, which changes what's performant and what's not. It's likely that the perforance gain from caching reference is less now than when the advice was written.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have given appears to simply be Javascript, not jQuery. Since you are using direct object property references and array indices to existing Javascript objects, there is no lookup involved. So in your case, adding `var currentObj...` could potentially *increase* overhead by the small amount needed to instantiate `currentObj`. Though this is likely very minor, and not uncommon for convenience and readability in code, in a long loop, you could possibly see the difference when timing it.

The caching you are probably thinking of has to do with jQuery objects, e.g.

```
var currentObj = $('some_selector');
```

Running a jQuery selector involves a significant amount of processing because it must look through the entire DOM (or some subset of it) to resolve the selector. So doing this, versus running the selector each time you refer to something, can indeed save a lot of overhead. But that's not what you're doing in your example.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SGqGu/7/

In firefox and chrome (didn't test IE) -- the time is identical in pretty much any scenario.

Comment: Yes, there is a lookup involved. Each object member access needs a lookup in the set of members in the object, but it's of course not nearly as expensive as looking for an element in the DOM.

Comment: Looking up object properties definitely takes time.

Comment: If javascript was 100% interpreted that would be true, but as the other answer says, these days, javascript is compiled in some way before being executed. References to object properties are *references* and are probably going to resolve to an internal pointer either way.

Comment: See edit... as it turns out it's actually *much* faster to *not* create a "cached" version of a raw object reference.

Comment: Oops, my fiddle was flawed.. fixed now. Actually it's nearly identical using any method. So unfortunately I didn't discover some great secret but I did confirm that caching object refs doesn't really do anything for you.

Comment: I corrected the test so that it compares apples to apples... You were adding `"x"` in one tests and `x` in the others. Getting the string representation of an object is what made some tests a lot slower. Using a reference seems to be about 30% faster than the other methods. http://jsfiddle.net/SGqGu/4/

Comment: I realized that. I'm seeing nearly insignificant differences in using a reference in repeated tests on Chrome and firefox. On chrome, I get 183 for a hard ref, and 171 for a variable over 7 million iterations. On FF (which is much slower) I get 389 vs 383. While it is usually repeatable that the variable is faster, the margin is so small as to be inconsequential and could even have to do with it being fewer characters in the script.

Comment: By the way use this one: http://jsfiddle.net/SGqGu/7/ in the last version, it was adding a hard string "x". In this version it adds a variable. I think that `e+"x"` was being unfairly optimized which is why you saw greater differences. I do consistently get Chrome being faster by 5-8%.  With firefox, the difference is not outside the margin of error (sometimes it's slower either way).

Answer (score 0):

> Is what I learnt true (meaning either
>   I am overusing it or mis-implemented
>   it)? Or are there any other aspects to
>   it that I am unaware of..?

It's not obvious if either is the case because you didn't post a link to your code.

I think most of your confusion comes from the fact that JavaScript developers are mainly concerned with caching DOM objects. DOM object lookups are substantially more expensive than looking up something like `myobj.something.something2`. I'd hazard a guess that most of what you've been reading about the importance of caching are examples like this (since you mentioned jQuery):

```
var myButton = $('#my_button');
```

In such cases, caching the DOM references can pay dividends in speed on pages with a complex DOM. With your example, it'd probably just reduce the readability of the code by making you have to remember that `currentObj` is just an alias to another object. In a loop, that'd make sense, but elsewhere, it wouldn't be worth having another variable to remember.